# How to set category gap in relative units in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

Suppose I would like to make a gap between bars the same as the size of bars. If the units were percents, I would set `100`. But this doesn't work:

```
public class StackedBarChart_Horizontal_Try extends Application {

    final static String itemA = "A";
    final static String itemB = "B";
    final static String itemC = "C";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();

        final StackedBarChart<Number, String> bc = new StackedBarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);

        //bc.setBarGap(0);
        bc.setCategoryGap(100);




        bc.setTitle("Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Value");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Item");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, itemA));


        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(41, itemB));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, itemC));

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

gives

[image]

and the size of gap remains constant on window resize:

[image]

This means gap is set in screen pixels.

How to set gap in size of axis unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of the bar chart works in a way that is counter to what you want to achieve here: given the height of the plot area, the layout mechanism first allocates the space for the gaps, then computes the size of the bars based on the remaining space available.

So the way to do this is to bind the `categoryGapProperty` to the correct size given the number of bars and the height of the plot area (which is the same as the height of the y-axis). To allocate the same amount of space to the gap and to the bars, you need the gap to be the total height divided by double the number of bars:

```
bc.categoryGapProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
    yAxis.getHeight() / (2 * bc.getData().size()), 
    Bindings.size(bc.getData()), yAxis.heightProperty()));
```

Complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackedBarChart_Horizontal_Try extends Application {

    final static String itemA = "A";
    final static String itemB = "B";
    final static String itemC = "C";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();

        final StackedBarChart<Number, String> bc = new StackedBarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);

        //bc.setBarGap(0);
//        bc.setCategoryGap(100);

        bc.categoryGapProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
            yAxis.getHeight() / (2 * bc.getData().size()), 
            Bindings.size(bc.getData()), yAxis.heightProperty()));


        bc.setTitle("Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Value");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Item");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, itemA));


        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(41, itemB));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, itemC));

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Which renders, at various window sizes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Dims To some extent, maybe, because you are trying to change the priority of allocation of space, for which there is no direct API. OTOH, the chart exposes `categoryGapProperty()` as a fully writable and bindable property, so it is fair to assume that binding it to something is an expected use case. The binding here is simply expressing "gaps should always be half the available space" in a pretty direct manner.